# Is it possible to hold multiple working holiday visas across multiple Schengen countries at one time?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, international-travel, working-holiday

I'm planning a trip to Europe where I plan to travel between multiple countries in Europe and the UK for upwards to a year.

Although I do not intend on "working working" per se, I am interested in WWOOFing in countries throughout the Schengen area and wondering what my best options would be in terms of coordinating visas.

I am from New Zealand (25 years old) and can travel through most countries without a visa for upwards to three months at a time (or three months total in the Schengen), however, as my plans are not solid I want the freedom to stay in Europe for longer than this timeframe if I choose.

I'm looking at getting a working holiday visa for France, Italy and Ireland as well as (potentially) a UK ancestry visa - but wondered if it was possible to hold these all at the same time or whether I needed to choose one country over the other.

Has anyone else done something similar or can offer help? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I don't agree with the close voters that this belongs on Expats. The bilateral working-holiday-visa agreements I've checked state as a requirement that the traveler's _main purpose_ must be the holiday, with (temporary) work being an incidental part of the trip. Therefore it doesn't seem to be really a question about _relocation_, which would belong on Expats.

Comment: Here is why I voted: Looking at [expatriates.se] on-topic page: "_Questions about work, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for **staying in the country for more time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow**_" which is _explicitly_ what the OP is asking about. We will have to agree to disagree, but then, you are free to answer this question there, if the OP, in fact, asks it there, or it gets moved.

Comment: @CGCampbell: Just because the question would be on-topic on Expats doesn't mean that it is automatically off-topic here. There is no presumption that different SE sites are necessarily completely disjoint -- for example there are pretty large areas that are on topic on both [math.se] and [cs.se].